# How to select the first N rows of each group?

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group, limit-per-group

I have two SQLite tables like this:

```
 AuthorId | AuthorName
----------------------
 1        | Alice
 2        | Bob
 3        | Carol
 ...      | ....


 BookId | AuthorId | Title
----------------------------------
 1      | 1        | aaa1
 2      | 1        | aaa2
 3      | 1        | aaa3
 4      | 2        | ddd1
 5      | 2        | ddd2
 ...    | ...      | ...
 19     | 3        | fff1
 20     | 3        | fff2
 21     | 3        | fff3
 22     | 3        | fff4
```

I want to make a SELECT query that will return the first N (e.g. two) rows for each AuthorId, ordering by Title ("Select the first two books of each author").

Sample output:

```
 BookId |  AuthorId | AuthorName | Title
------------------------------------------
 1      |  1        |   Alice    | aaa1
 2      |  1        |   Alice    | aaa1
 4      |  2        |   Bob      | ddd1
 5      |  2        |   Bob      | ddd2
 19     |  3        |   Carol    | fff1
 20     |  3        |   Carol    | fff2
```

How can I build this query?

(Yes, I found a similar topic, and I know how to return only one row (first or top). The problem is with the two).

Comment: Someone had a similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518900/how-to-find-teams-with-sql-command

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do the counting using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT b.BookId, a.AuthorId, a.AuthorName, b.Title
FROM Author a join
     Book b
     on a.AuthorId = b.AuthorId
where (select count(*)
       from book b2
       where b2.bookId <= b.BookId and b2.AuthorId = b.AuthorId
      ) <= 2;
```

For a small database this should be fine.  If you create a composite index on `Book(AuthorId, BookId)` then that will help the query.

Comment: For larger tables the composite index made a world of a difference (28.39 sec vs 1.84 sec). Pretty cool!

Answer (score 15):

There is alternative variant:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM BOOK, AUTHOR
    WHERE BOOK.AUTHORID = AUTHOR.AUTHORID
) T1
WHERE T1.BOOKID IN (
    SELECT T2.BOOKID FROM BOOK T2
    WHERE T2.AUTHORID = T1.AUTHORID
    ORDER BY T2.BOOKTITLE
    LIMIT 2
)
ORDER BY T1.BOOKTITLE
```

Comment: I liked this answer better for my particular case, but MySQL didn't support "limit" inside "in" subquery, so I had to go with the other solution... :( upvoted anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

Here you go. Might be too late but I just saw the post. You can change the <=2 to match the n you need.

```
SELECT 
 a.authorid,
 a.authorname,
 b.bookid,
 b.booktitle
FROM author a
JOIN book b ON b.authorid = b.authorid
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.authorid
ORDER BY   b.booktitle ASC) <=2
```

Comment: This does not `qualify` as an SQLite answer :-)