# SQLite - Top 10 of 5 different groups sorted by length

Tags: sql, sqlite, limit-per-group

I read many questions with the **greatest-n-per-group** tag, but I can't find a better solution than the `UNION ALL` trick for this SQL query :

```
select * from (select GroupName, JobName, Start, End, Status, (strftime('%s', End) - strftime('%s', Start)) as Length from ReportJobs where PlanDate = '2014-02-13' and GroupName like 'GRP01%' ORDER BY Length DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
select * from (select GroupName, JobName, Start, End, Status, (strftime('%s', End) - strftime('%s', Start)) as Length from ReportJobs where PlanDate = '2014-02-13' and GroupName like 'GRP04%' ORDER BY Length DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
select * from (select GroupName, JobName, Start, End, Status, (strftime('%s', End) - strftime('%s', Start)) as Length from ReportJobs where PlanDate = '2014-02-13' and GroupName like 'GRP12%' ORDER BY Length DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
select * from (select GroupName, JobName, Start, End, Status, (strftime('%s', End) - strftime('%s', Start)) as Length from ReportJobs where PlanDate = '2014-02-13' and GroupName like 'GRP15%' ORDER BY Length DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
select * from (select GroupName, JobName, Start, End, Status, (strftime('%s', End) - strftime('%s', Start)) as Length from ReportJobs where PlanDate = '2014-02-13' and GroupName like 'GRP20%' ORDER BY Length DESC LIMIT 10);
```

I want to select the ten longest jobs for five different groups (*GRP01%*, *GRP04%*, *GRP12%*, *GRP15%* and *GRP20%*).

I'm using SQLite.
Elements in `Start` and `End` columns are ISO 8601 formatted.
I use `(strftime('%s', End) - strftime('%s', Start)) as Length` to calculate the length of each job, then `ORDER BY Length DESC LIMIT 10` for each group.

Do you know a simplest/better way to perform this query (with SQLite)?

Comment: @CL. I already tried to adapt the queries from the answers you posted, without success. I have a single table (not two) and one value (`Length`) is calculated by the query.

Comment: related: [how to select first N row of each group?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17991943/11654)

Comment: Then edit the question to show what you've tried.