# select top n record from each group sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to select top 2 records from a database table result that looks like this

```
SubjectId |  StudentId | Levelid | total
------------------------------------------
 1        |  1         |   1     | 89
 1        |  2         |   1     | 77
 1        |  3         |   1     | 61
 2        |  4         |   1     | 60
 2        |  5         |   1     | 55
 2        |  6         |   1     | 45
```

i tried this query

```
SELECT rv.subjectid,
       rv.total,
       rv.Studentid,
       rv.levelid
  FROM ResultView rv
       LEFT JOIN ResultView rv2
              ON ( rv.subjectid = rv2.subjectid 
    AND
rv.total <= rv2.total ) 
 GROUP BY rv.subjectid,
          rv.total,
          rv.Studentid
HAVING COUNT( * ) <= 2
order by rv.subjectid desc
```

but some subjects like where missing, i even tried the suggestiong frm the following link

[How to select the first N rows of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991943/sqlite-how-to-select-first-n-row-of-each-group)

but i get more that two for each subjectid

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `HAVING COUNT( * ) <= 3` filters out any group with 3 or more rows.  But you're not looking to exclude entire groups, just any rows past the second one.

Comment: the `HAVING COUNT( * ) <= 3` was a typo, it has been corrected

Comment: If you provide an example of the desired output, it is easier to provide an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a correlated subquery:

```
select  *
from    ResultView rv1
where   SubjectId || '-' || StudentId || '-' || LevelId in
        (
        select  SubjectId || '-' || StudentId || '-' || LevelId
        from    ResultView rv2
        where   SubjectID = rv1.SubjectID
        order by
                total desc
        limit   2
        )
```

This query constructs a single-column primary key by concatenating three columns.  If you have a real primary key (like `ResultViewID`) you can substitute that for `SubjectId || '-' || StudentId || '-' || LevelId`.

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ecfd4/3/0)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i am getting a different result. The example i posted above is a simplified version of my problem, maybe that why. i will post a more details version. The table I am selecting from is actually a view which joins two tables by a common id .  if i want to select this result based in the levelid, where do i put the `where` clause?

Answer (score 8):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly.  Let me know if this is correct:

I recreated your table:

```
CREATE TABLE stack (
       SubjectId INTEGER(10),
       StudentId INTEGER(10),
       Levelid INTEGER(10),
       total INTEGER(10)
       )
;
```

Inserted values

```
INSERT INTO stack VALUES
       (1,1,1,89),
       (1,2,1,77),
       (1,3,1,61),
       (2,4,1,60),
       (2,5,1,55),
       (2,6,1,45)
;
```

If you're trying to get the top group by Levelid (orderd by total field, assuming StudentID as primary key):

```
SELECT * 
FROM stack AS a
WHERE a.StudentID IN (
      SELECT b.StudentID
      FROM stack AS b
      WHERE a.levelid = b.levelid
      ORDER BY b.total DESC
      LIMIT 2
      )
;
```

Yields this result:

```
SubjectId | StudentId | Levelid | total
1         | 1         | 1       | 89
1         | 2         | 1       | 77
```

Example of top 2 by SubjectId, ordered by total:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stack AS a
WHERE a.StudentID IN (
      SELECT b.StudentID
      FROM stack AS b
      WHERE a.subjectID = b.subjectID
      ORDER BY b.total DESC
      LIMIT 2
      )
;
```

Result:

```
SubjectId | StudentId | Levelid | total
1         | 1         | 1       | 89
1         | 2         | 1       | 77
2         | 4         | 1       | 60
2         | 5         | 1       | 55
```

I hope that was the answer you were looking for.

Comment: The good news that it works, the bad news is that it takes 30 seconds to execute per 10K records.

Answer (score 2):

**`ROW_NUMBER` window function**

SQLite now supports window functions, so the exact same code that works for PostgreSQL at [Grouped LIMIT in PostgreSQL: show the first N rows for each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124603/grouped-limit-in-postgresql-show-the-first-n-rows-for-each-group/6064141#6064141) now also works for SQLite.

This could be potentially faster than the other answers so far as it does not run a correlated subquery.

Supposing you want to get the 2 highest `total` rows for each `StudentID`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY "StudentID"
        ORDER BY "total" DESC
      ) AS "rnk",
      *
    FROM "mytable"
  ) sub
WHERE
  "sub"."rnk" <= 2
ORDER BY
  "sub"."StudentID" ASC,
  "sub"."total" DESC
```

Tested on SQLite 3.34, PostgreSQL 14.3. [GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/blob/2ea910f407098ad3c7fac9f25af585f7e4cff4b1/nodejs/sequelize/raw/group_by_max_n.js)