# How to get the "top 10" numbers per object in SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite-table with columns author, book, release_date and seller.

Now I need to find a way to get only the top 10 books of each author with the latest release_date.

If possible, I also need the seller, that appears "most often" in the top 10 latest released books per author. The result should be a simple table with author and seller only.

This problem is really driving me crazy.
Is at minimum one part possible in a single SQLite-query???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select top n record from each group sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119176/select-top-n-record-from-each-group-sqlite)

Comment: Read the above link, which contains a number of ways to approach your problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen SQLIte supports windowing and ranking functions yet none of the answers to the linked question uses them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, a good link, if we assume that the versions of SQLite for which those answers were written do not support window functions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Someone can always add an example using window functions to that question. I might when I have a chance to if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: the solution from the link might work, but in my sample, i have database with 10 mio. entries. the below solution via window_function finished in 10 seconds. the solution from the link runs some hours (I never waited till the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite v3.25 which came out in September 2018 added [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html).

You can calculate the rank of a book by date for each author with :

```
CREATE TABLE books
(
  author varchar(10),
  title varchar(10),
  release date
);
INSERT INTO books VALUES 
('aaa','ta1','2018-01-01'),
('aaa','ta2','2018-02-01'),
('aaa','ta3','2018-03-01'),
('aaa','ta4','2018-05-01'),
('bbb','tb1','2018-05-01'),
('bbb','tb2','2018-06-01')
;

SELECT
    author,
    title,
    release, 
    row_number() OVER (partition by author ORDER BY release desc) AS row_number 
FROM books
```

The function `row_number() OVER (partition by author ORDER BY release desc) AS row_number` calculates the row number for each author if the rows are ordered by release date.

This produces :

```
author  title   release     row_number
aaa     ta4     2018-05-01  1
aaa     ta3     2018-03-01  2
aaa     ta2     2018-02-01  3
aaa     ta1     2018-01-01  4
bbb     tb2     2018-06-01  1
bbb     tb1     2018-05-01  2
```

Once you have the row number, you can filter the top N items with a simple `WHERE row_number <= N`, eg for the last 2 books per author :

```
select * from (
SELECT
    author,
    title,
    release, 
    row_number() OVER (partition by author ORDER BY release desc) AS row_number 
FROM books )
where row_number<=2
```

This returns :

```
author  title   release     row_number
aaa    ta4      2018-05-01  1
aaa    ta3      2018-03-01  2
bbb    tb2      2018-06-01  1
bbb    tb1      2018-05-01  2
```

Comment: outstanding! many thanks for this huge help. any solution idea for the 2nd challenge to get the most appearing seller in the latest top 10? how can i combine counting and grouping here (in case this is the right direction)?