# How to select first row for each set of rows with common value

Tags: sql, sql-server

As an example I have a a table like this:

```
week_dt     cust    y_w     w   y       y_fp
2011-01-29  ABC     201122  6   2011    201106
2011-02-05  ABC     201123  6   2011    201106
2011-02-12  ABC     201124  6   2011    201106
2011-02-19  ABC     201125  7   2011    201107
2011-02-26  ABC     201126  7   2011    201107
2011-03-05  ABC     201127  7   2011    201107
2011-03-12  ABC     201128  7   2011    201107
2011-03-19  ABC     201129  8   2011    201108
2011-03-26  ABC     201130  8   2011    201108
2011-04-02  ABC     201131  8   2011    201108
2011-04-09  ABC     201132  8   2011    201108
2011-04-16  ABC     201133  9   2011    201109
2011-04-23  ABC     201134  9   2011    201109
```

The last column contains year/fiscal period info. I would like to select one row for each `y_fp` element with `week_dt` and `y_w` being the first date for that year/fiscal period. Thus selecting from the above would yield:

```
week_dt     cust    y_w     w   y       y_fp
2011-01-29  ABC     201122  6   2011    201106
2011-02-19  ABC     201125  7   2011    201107
2011-03-19  ABC     201129  8   2011    201108
2011-04-16  ABC     201133  9   2011    201109
```

I've tried following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991943/how-to-select-the-first-n-rows-of-each-group) using `TOP(1)` instead of `LIMIT` but I got the entire table returned to me.

This was my query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT
    md.week_dt, 
    md.cust, 
    md.y_w, 
    md.y, 
    md.w, 
    md.y_fp, 
    FROM MASTER_DATES md
) t1
Where 
    t1.week_dt IN (
    SELECT TOP(1) t2.week_dt
    FROM MASTER_DATES t2
    WHERE t2.week_dt = t1.week_dt AND t2.cust = t1.cust
    ORDER BY t2.week_dt
)
ORDER BY t1.week_dt
```

Note that MASTER_DATES contains a composite primary key from columns `week_dt` and `cust`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use row_number and a partition by to divide it by md.y_fp

```
WITH C AS(
 SELECT
    md.week_dt, 
    md.cust, 
    md.y_w, 
    md.y, 
    md.w, 
    md.y_fp,
    row_number() over(partition by md.y_fp order by md.week_dt asc) as rn
FROM MASTER_DATES md
)
SELECT * 
FROM C 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is `row_number()`:

```
select md.*
from (select md.*,
             row_number() over (partition by md.cust, md.y_fp order by md.week_date desc) as seqnum
      from master_dates md
     ) md
where seqnum = 1;
```

In some cases, though, a correlated subquery has better performance:

```
select md.*
from master_dates md
where md.week_date = (select min(md2.week_date)
                      from master_dates md2
                      where md2.cust = md.cust and md2.y_fp = md.y_fp
                     );
```

For best performance, you want an index on `(cust, y_fp, week_date)`.

These answer assume that you want the information per customer, although that is not explicitly stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data and expected results indicate that a simple group by is enough:

```
select
  min(week_dt) week_dt, 
  cust,
  min(y_w) y_w,
  w,
  y,
  y_fp
from MASTER_DATES 
group by cust, y, w, y_fp
```

Comment: Sorry the duplicate y column was an accident. I'll edit that. And yes this seems to have worked as well and is very simple.

Comment: You need grouping and the minimum values of 2 columns. That's it.